# Assignment rules is not working while records are inserting into lead from dataloader

Tags: data-loader, assignment-rules

While i am inserting manually, assignment rules are comes into action if i checked `Assign using active assignment rule` option. But while inserting records from data loader, assignment rules are not working.

I mentioned assignment rule in dataloader like path shows `settings-->Assignmentrule-->Assignmentrulename`(in dataloader). Even though dataloader giving error like

> Bad id Assignmentrulename

Please help me to get out of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the **ID** of the assignment rule in the space provided.

From the error you posted it looks like you are using `Assignmentrulename` which is a placeholder. Even so you need to use the ID

Comment: Great. Assignment rules are working now 
Thank you.